# sass with auto-refresh using parcel , getting errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT' when running start script

Tags: sass, parcel

I'm trying to setup Sass with auto-refresh using parcel,

and when I'm using script "start": "parcel src/index.html", I'm constantly getting the following error:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\vscodeprojects\RSSchool\dict\dict.txt'
at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
at makeCompression (D:\vscodeprojects\RSSchool\Stage#1\imdenver-JSFELT\english_for_kids\node_modules\lmdb\dist\index.cjs:2047:19)
at Object.open (D:\vscodeprojects\RSSchool\Stage#1\imdenver-JSFELT\english_for_kids\node_modules\lmdb\dist\index.cjs:2057:25)
at new LMDBCache (D:\vscodeprojects\RSSchool\Stage#1\imdenver-JSFELT\english_for_kids\node_modules@parcel\cache\lib\LMDBCache.js:81:34)
at resolveOptions (D:\vscodeprojects\RSSchool\Stage#1\imdenver-JSFELT\english_for_kids\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\resolveOptions.js:125:168)
at async Parcel._init (D:\vscodeprojects\RSSchool\Stage#1\imdenver-JSFELT\english_for_kids\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:218:27)
at async Parcel.watch (D:\vscodeprojects\RSSchool\Stage#1\imdenver-JSFELT\english_for_kids\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:315:7)
at async run (D:\vscodeprojects\RSSchool\Stage#1\imdenver-JSFELT\english_for_kids\node_modules\parcel\lib\cli.js:351:9) {
errno: -4058,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'D:\vscodeprojects\RSSchool\dict\dict.txt'
}

This dict file outside of the project folder doesn't make sense.

Please advise.

Comment: If you are using `package.json` only `"start": "parcel"` will do the job of creating a dev server and starting it.

Comment: might be, but error stays the same, i tried different variations and all of them fail

Comment: Could you share your entire parcel config

Comment: Please advise what exactly i need to provide, I am not really sure what parcel config is

Comment: Try adding a this in your package.json `"source": "src/index.html"` and replacing `"start":"parcel src/index.html"` with `"start":"parcel"`

Comment: also tried, I'm sitting like 2 days in a row on this issue, and seems like there is some problem with modules, missing some files or wrong paths idk

Comment: Could you share the repo on github

Comment: https://github.com/IMDENVER/Project_structure.git

Answer (score 0):

I cloned into your repo and run with below `package.json` config

Replaced `"start":"parcel src/index.html"` with `"start":"parcel"`

[image]

App runs

[image]

Comment: Friend of mine runs it without any issues as well, i opened one of the links provided by error, and found this strange path: https://prnt.sc/jFZAvTLF-dcD . Any idea how it is appears every time? I have clean parcel v2.6.2 installed

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules` folder and reinstalling it with `npm install`

Comment: it was done, more than that- i tried all versions of parcel v2, from 2.0.0 up the the very last 2.6.2- the same error keep happening, i do not really understand how this path appears all the time

Comment: Try moving your project repo into another folder somewhere else without `node_modules` and then run `npm install`

Comment: well it worked lol, but what was that?

Comment: Well not sure, what was that. But sometimes you have to do things like this to make it work !!